# How to migrate ngExpressEngine in Angular 16 SSR to work with Angular 17

Tags: angular, migration

I am cherry picking the exact relevant piece of code from my Angular 16(now Angular 17) server.ts file.

```
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';


server.engine(
    'html',
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  })
);
```

Angular 17 no longer has the ngExpressEngine, and replacing with the new CommonEngine from angular/ssr does not work.

I am open to suggestions if anyone knows how to properly migrate. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use the syntax here to solve. Just swap out code in my question for code here

```
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';


const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;
    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: distFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve the issue when i have multiple "server.gets" for different paths? I think we do not have to repeat all the commonEngine.render lines for all the routes..

Comment: ask it as a question and I'll answer there. Comment not enough details just yet

Comment: There is a [great guide](https://medium.com/@aayyash/replacing-angular-universal-with-ssr-version-f257dfae305f) that I just came across that might help you with the conversion. (In that guide they show how to use the CommonEngine as middleware).

Comment: cool well if want to use https://razroo.com/finder/razroo/angular-universal-with-aws-17.0.0 can use that to setup up angular universal (it's a one click integration)